# Shift all non-null elements to the left

Tags: c, sorting, matrix

The elements must be shifted to the left if they are 0. I tried a loop that starts from the end of the 2D Matrix Array, but I can't seem to get my head around why it doesn't work.

The input must be in range -999 to 999.

I assign the element that is != 0 to the first index and afterwards if have to move that temporary integer one step forward. That is my main issue, since I can't get my head around it. Perhaps a different approach is wanted?

(I'm trying to solve it without Pointers)

```
int main()
{
    int M[3][3];
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
            printf("Give me the number for [%d][%d]: ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &M[i][j]);

            if(-999 > M[i][j] || M[i][j] > 999) j--;
            // a)
            if((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
                M[i][j] = 0;
            }

        }
    }
    // Print the result of a) 
    for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
            printf("%d ", M[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Shifting the elements to the left  b)
    int temp = M[0][0];
    for(i = 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for(j = 2; j >= 0; j--){
            if(M[i][j] != 0)
            {
                M[i][j] = temp;
            }
            // change the value of temp
        }
    }
    // Print the array after a) and b)
    for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
            printf("%d ", M[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

The result of the a) is just the matrix after the first step where if (i=j) converts the value at that place 0.

For example if you input: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
The result would be: 0 2 0 4 0 6 0 8 0
The final result of b) is yet to be done, but should look like:
2 4 6 8 0 0 0 0 0.

Answer (score 1):

> Perhaps a different approach is wanted?

As a [3][3] array is in memory like a [1][3*3] one, simple shift `M[0]` as if it had 9 elements.

```
unsigned nonzero_index = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 3*3; ++i){
  if (M[0][i]) {
    M[0][nonzero_index++] = M[0][i];
  }
}
while (nonzero_index < 3*3) { //  zero fill the rest
  M[0][nonzero_index++] = 0;
}
```